# unable to read file in java spark

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark

I am trying to run the spark program on java using eclipse. Its is running if i simply print something on console but I am not able to read any file using textFile function. 
I have read somewhere that reading  a file can only be done using HDFS but I am not able to do in my local system.
Do let me know how to access/read file , if using HDFS then how to install HDFS in my local system so that i can rad the text file.

Here's a code on which I am testing , though this program is working fine but it is unable to read file saying Input path does not exist.

```
package spark;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;

import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;

public class TestSpark {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String[] jars = {"D:\\customJars\\spark.jar"};
        System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "D:\\hadoop-common-2.2.0-bin-master");
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("spark.TestSpark")
                .setMaster("spark://10.1.50.165:7077")
                .setJars(jars);

        JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
        SQLContext sqlcon = new SQLContext(jsc);
        String inputFileName = "./forecaster.txt" ;
        JavaRDD<String> logData = jsc.textFile(inputFileName);
        long numAs = logData.filter(new Function<String, Boolean>() {

            @Override
            public Boolean call(String s) throws Exception {
                return s.contains("a");
            }
        }).count();

        long numBs = logData.filter(new Function<String, Boolean>() {
              public Boolean call(String s) { return s.contains("b"); }
            }).count();

         System.out.println("Lines with a: " + numAs + ", lines with b: " + numBs);
        System.out.println("sadasdasdf");

        jsc.stop();
        jsc.close();
    }

}
```

My File Struture :
[image]

Comment: Can you add the error log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: you don't have `.txt` extension in file name and you are using it in your application. You should use it as `String inputFileName = "forecaster" ;`

If file is in same folder as java class `TestSpark` (`$APP_HOME`):

```
String inputFileName = "forecaster.txt" ;
```

If file is in Data dir under your project of spark:

```
String inputFileName = "Data\\forecaster.txt" ;
```

Or use fully qualified Path log says from below testing:

```
16/08/03 08:25:25 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:/C:/Users/user123/worksapce/spark-java/forecaster.txt
~~~~~~~
String inputFileName = "file:/C:/Users/user123/worksapce/spark-java/forecaster.txt" ;
```

For example: I copied your code and ran on my local environment:

this is how my project step up is, and I run it as:

```
 String inputFileName = "forecaster.txt" ;
```

**Test File:**

```
this is test file
aaa
bbb
ddddaaee
ewwww
aaaa
a
a
aaaa
bb
```

[image]

**Code that I used:**

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;

public class TestSpark {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
       // String[] jars = {"D:\\customJars\\spark.jar"};
       // System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "D:\\hadoop-common-2.2.0-bin-master");
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("spark.TestSpark").setMaster("local");
                //.setMaster("spark://10.1.50.165:7077")
                //.setJars(jars);

        JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
        //SQLContext sqlcon = new SQLContext(jsc);
        String inputFileName = "forecaster.txt" ;
        JavaRDD<String> logData = jsc.textFile(inputFileName);
        long numAs = logData.filter(new Function<String, Boolean>() {

            @Override
            public Boolean call(String s) throws Exception {
                return s.contains("a");
            }
        }).count();

        long numBs = logData.filter(new Function<String, Boolean>() {

            public Boolean call(String s) { return s.contains("b"); }
            }).count();

         System.out.println("Lines with a: " + numAs + ", lines with b: " + numBs);
        System.out.println("sadasdasdf");

        jsc.stop();
        jsc.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Still i am facing the same issue ....                                                       Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/D:/workspace2/SparkPOC/forecaster.txt
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:285)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:228)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:313)
 at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:199)

Comment: can you share your project structure in question? which inputpath you used? (fully qualified or just filename)? also can you ensure filename is correct?

Comment: There u go...you don't have `txt` extension in file name - see update in answer

Comment: Bingo it works!!!!! Thanks a lot ....  Now help me with the procedure to put the porgram on different machine to see the actual performance as a cluster computing

Comment: great...this should be a separate question - please make this as an accepted answer (make the correct sign green) - and create new thread for your next question...but hint: (create a jar of your application and run it with `sprk-submit` )

Answer (score 1):

Spark needs schema and proper path in order to understand how to read the file. So if you are reading from HDFS, you should use:

```
jsc.textFile("hdfs://host/path/to/hdfs/file/input.txt");
```

If you are reading local file (local to the worker node, not the machine the driver is running), you should use:

```
jsc.textFile("file://path/to/hdfs/file/input.txt");
```

For reading Hadoop Archive File (HAR), you should use:

```
jsc.textFile("har://archive/path/to/hdfs/file/input.txt");
```

And so on.